# How can I append the content of streams in C#?

Tags: c#

I am copying one stream to another to get one complete stream at the end and then to save the stream in .wav form, but I am getting the content of first part of the stream.

I am developing recorder with record, pause, stop functionality. When I press the record button, I get a stream and copy this stream to another in the stop button, then I repeat these steps, and when I merge all stream at one place/stream, I only get the content of first copying stream.

```
public void CopyInputStreamToOutput(Stream fromStream, MemoryStream destination)
{
    int num;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fromStream.Length];
    fromStream.Position = 0;
    while ((num = fromStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        destination.Write(buffer, 0, num);
    }
}
```

I need this: *stream1+stream2+stream3+...+streamN=finalStream*. How to append one stream to another to get the final stream?

Is there any problem in the position?

Comment: Stream.CopyTo Method ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932(v=vs.110).aspx

lack of search...

Comment: actually i need this     Stream1+stream2+stream3= finalstream???

Comment: jordsti what kind of question is this? i did all that but the question is i am getting one stream1 after using the above function

Comment: Because it's a really simple problem that you can answer by just reading the documentation and try a solution. By the way, if you want to work with Audio file, you need an audio library, just merging the bytes of different wav file will just create a bugged wav files..

Comment: i did that already dude, i think the whole problem is in fromStream.Position = 0;  if i repeat this many how can i handle this poisiton?

Comment: Read the doc please... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Stream_methods(v=vs.110).aspx 

Seek() Method will place you at the specific place in the file. But when you open a stream, it suppose to be at 0. If it's not in Append Mode.

Comment: @jordsti Check out the [Help Center article here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior): "*Be nice.  Civility is required at all times; rudeness will not be tolerated. Treat others with the same respect you’d want them to treat you because we’re all here to learn, together. Be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know...*"  Asking someone, who is honestly trying to understand a problem with their program, "Do you know how to program?" is ***incredibly*** rude.

Comment: @jordsti If this is such a simple problem, then why not make that solution an answer?

Comment: @Bart Because I don't write a solution when he can do it by his self, just by taking 5 minutes and reading this official documentation. I know that I respond rudely to his question, but I saw his previous question and this guy don't need an answer, but to do some tutorial to learn how to code, because he clearly doesn't know... And you know what we said normally to people that can resolve their problem by reading the docs... RTFM!

Comment: @jordsti, EVERY problem on EVERY board can be answered by RTFM. We save time by brainstorming or jump-starting our understanding of TFM by posting dumb questions.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I am taking a guess with this - not an expert in the area. Please consider it as pseudo-code</strike>

```
public void CopyInputStreamToOutput(Stream fromStream, MemoryStream destination)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    ms.Write(destination.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)destination.Length); 
    ms.Write(fromStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fromStream.Length); 
    destination = ms;
}
```

This is working:

```
public static void CopyInputStreamToOutput(Stream fromStream, ref MemoryStream destination)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    destination.Position = 0;
    destination.CopyTo(ms);
    fromStream.Position = 0;
    fromStream.CopyTo(ms);
    destination = ms;
}
```

This is even better because it doesn't create the extra copy but may have to consider `destination` position. Documantation for `CopyTo` states `does not reset the position of the destination stream after the copy operation is complete.`:

```
public static void CopyInputStreamToOutput(Stream fromStream, ref MemoryStream destination)
{
    //MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    //destination.Position = 0;
    //destination.CopyTo(ms);
    fromStream.Position = 0;
    fromStream.CopyTo(destination);
    //destination = ms;
}
```

Comment: Um, I would have returned a new stream with the others appended or appended to the "original stream, but yes that should work.